# Dynamically update react-google-chart type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use a select box to change the chart type of a react-google-chart. Code looks like this:

```
const GoogleGraph = ({chartType, handleChartTypeChange}) => (
        <section>
            <Selector
                chartType={chartType}
                handleChartTypeChange={handleChartTypeChange}
            />
            <Chart
                chartType={chartType}
                data={data}
                options={options}
                graphID={chartType}
                width="100%"
                height="10em"
                chartEvents={chartEvents}
            />
        </section>
    );
```

When the select box is changed I am getting the data I expect as I can see in the debugger that the chartType prop has changed from "Bar" to "Line" however the chart remains a bar chart after render completes. I do not get an error.

Is it possible to update the chartType dynamically?

Comment: Looks like it should be possible: https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/blob/742f7673dd8243badcbfbd194960d0bd6df2a17b/src/ReactGoogleCharts.tsx#L388

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all else fails, you can also use the `chartType` as `key` which will make React throw away the current component and create an entirely new one when the `chartType` changes.

```
const GoogleGraph = ({ chartType, handleChartTypeChange }) => (
  <section>
    <Selector
      chartType={chartType}
      handleChartTypeChange={handleChartTypeChange}
    />
    <Chart
      key={chartType}
      chartType={chartType}
      data={data}
      options={options}
      graphID={chartType}
      width="100%"
      height="10em"
      chartEvents={chartEvents}
    />
  </section>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to a generic HTML Select

```js
const GoogleGraph = ({ chartType, handleChartTypeChange, data, options }) => (
 <section>
  <select value={chartType} onChange={handleChartTypeChange}>
   <option value="PieChart">PieChart</option>
   <option value="BarChart">BarChart</option>
  </select>
  <Chart
   key={chartType}
   chartType={chartType}
   width={'80vw'}
   height={'80vh'}
   loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
   data={data}
   options={options}
   graphID={chartType}
  />
 </section>
);
```